# How to generate a thumbnail of flash movie (.flv)

Tags: coldfusion, ffmpeg, image-manipulation

I'm using ColdFusion and need to generate a thumbnail from a flash movie stored on the server. I have heard of ffMpeg but have no idea how to use it. (Once you put it on your server what's the next step?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cfexecute](http://cfmldocs.com/cfexecute.html) to run a command line on the CF server.

Karthik linked a blog post that suggests the following syntax for ffmpeg:

> ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.avi
>   -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg

So you could do something like this:

```
<cfexecute 
    name="c:\pathto\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"
    arguments="-itsoffset -4  -i #sourcevideo# -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 #thumbnaildestination" />
```

I haven't run ffmpeg like this and you'll likely need to experiment with the syntax to get a result you like, but once you do your workflow is pretty straightforward.

You may also run into issues executing `fmpeg.exe` depending on the user account your ColdFusion server instance is running as.

Comment: thanks, I was wondering how you use the ffmpeg command but I see that it goes in a cfexecute tag.

Comment: I did a search through the folder and also manually looked through all of the folders and there is no ffmpeg.exe or any file that has an extension of .exe. Which file do I need to point to?

Comment: @nick is your CF server on windows or some other OS?

Comment: windows, I figured it out though, I found a copy that was already compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of FFMpeg: http://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html

You might want to check: http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/

http://www.flashcomguru.com/index.cfm/2006/4/25/ffmpegthumbs

with ColdFusion its not possible but check this: http://old.nabble.com/Create-a-thumbnail-image-from-.flv-video-file-once-uploaded-td22683497.html

Comment: although it's true to say that there is no native method to do this in ColdFusion it's not entirely accurate to say it is not possible.

Comment: I am not aware of ColdFusion but I have tried FFMPEG in the past.